# Mapping Cheerio objects into an array of "native" objects

Tags: typescript, cheerio

I have the following HTML (repeated a few times with different data) in a document that I have loaded via [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/):

```
<li class="wprm-recipe-ingredient">
  <span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-amount">1</span>
  <span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-unit">pound</span>
  <span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-name">extra lean ground beef</span>
</li>
```

Here is the code I have written that expresses my intent:

```
const $ingredients = $("li[class='wprm-recipe-ingredient']");

const ingredients = $ingredients.map((_idx, $e) => {
    const $elem = $($e);
    const amount = $elem.children('[class$="-amount"]').text();
    const unit = $elem.children('[class$="-unit"]').text();
    const name = $elem.children('[class$="-name"]').text();
    return { amount, unit, name };
}); // => [{amount, unit, name}, { ... }]
```

But that comment illustrates what I desire not what I actually get.

The actual type is `const ingredients: Cheerio`, which is not an array of anonymous objects with the shape I've attempted to create.

How can I map `$ingredients` into the following shape?

```
[{ amount: '1', unit: 'pound', name: 'extra lean ground beef' }]
```

---

Note that Cheerio's `.get()` returns either `string[]` or `CheerioElement[]` so that is not what I want as far as I can tell.

---

**Edit**:

I should expand on this a bit.

What I am currently doing is creating an array up-front then `push`ing onto that array at the end of the `$ingredients.forEach(...)` closure.

Comment: you need to return `{amount: amount, unit: unit, ...}`

Comment: What I am returning is the shorthand syntax for what you've described and using the long-form doesn't change the signature of `Cheerio.map` which is, as far as I can tell, the root of my issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd spread the iterable to a traditional array and use the native `.map` on it:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<li class="wprm-recipe-ingredient">
  <span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-amount">1</span>
  <span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-unit">pound</span>
  <span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-name">extra lean ground beef</span>
</li>
`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const result = [...$(".wprm-recipe-ingredient")].map(e => ({
  amount: $(e).find(".wprm-recipe-ingredient-amount").text(),
  unit: $(e).find(".wprm-recipe-ingredient-unit").text(),
  name: $(e).find(".wprm-recipe-ingredient-name").text(),
}));
console.log(result);
```

This gives:

```
[ { amount: '1', unit: 'pound', name: 'extra lean ground beef' } ]
```